# Unable to install awstats on redhat 7 due to missing perl(LWP::UserAgent)

Tags: redhat, rpm, awstats, rhel7

I'm unable to install `awstats` on my `rhel7` `aws` `ec2` instance:

```
[root@ip-10-146-180-60 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo)
[root@ip-10-146-180-60 ~]# rpm -ivh http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/awstats/awstats-7.3-1.noarch.rpm
Retrieving http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/awstats/awstats-7.3-1.noarch.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    perl(LWP::UserAgent) is needed by awstats-7.3-1.noarch
[root@ip-10-146-180-60 ~]#
```

`awstats-7.3-1.noarch.rpm` was also looking for `perl-Digest-MD5` (`perl-Digest` is one of the dependencies for `perl-Digest-MD5`):

```
[root@ip-10-146-180-60 ~]# tail -2 /var/log/yum.log 
Sep 16 21:46:39 Installed: perl-Digest-1.17-245.el7.noarch
Sep 16 21:46:39 Installed: perl-Digest-MD5-2.52-3.el7.x86_64
[root@ip-10-146-180-60 ~]#
```

I was able to install these, but I'm unable to find `perl(LWP::UserAgent)` for `rhel7`.

```
[root@ip-10-146-180-60 ~]# yum --enablerepo=* list all | grep perl-LWP
perl-LWP-Authen-Negotiate.noarch
perl-LWP-MediaTypes.noarch     6.02-2.el7       rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
perl-LWP-Protocol-http10.noarch
perl-LWP-Protocol-https.noarch 6.04-4.el7       rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
[root@ip-10-146-180-60 ~]#
```

`yum --enablerepo=* repolist` output:

```
[root@ip-10-146-180-60 ~]# yum --enablerepo=* repolist
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb
repo id                                                                                                       repo name                                                                                                                 status
epel/x86_64                                                                                                   Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                            5,618
epel-debuginfo/x86_64                                                                                         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Debug                                                                    1,328
epel-source/x86_64                                                                                            Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Source                                                                       0
epel-testing/x86_64                                                                                           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - x86_64                                                                    523
epel-testing-debuginfo/x86_64                                                                                 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - x86_64 - Debug                                                            104
epel-testing-source/x86_64                                                                                    Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - x86_64 - Source                                                             0
remi                                                                                                          Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                          1,424
remi-debuginfo/x86_64                                                                                         Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                                                                494
remi-php55                                                                                                    Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.5 pour Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                 233
remi-php55-debuginfo/x86_64                                                                                   Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.5 pour Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                                                     138
remi-php56                                                                                                    Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.6 pour Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                 237
remi-php56-debuginfo/x86_64                                                                                   Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.6 pour Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                                                     141
remi-test                                                                                                     Les RPM de remi en test pour Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                     56
remi-test-debuginfo/x86_64                                                                                    Les RPM de remi en test pour Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                                                          5
rhui-REGION-client-config-server-7/x86_64                                                                     Red Hat Update Infrastructure 2.0 Client Configuration Server 7                                                               2
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-debug-extras/7Server/x86_64                                                           Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Extra Debug (Debug RPMs)                                                                    4
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-debug-optional/7Server/x86_64                                                         Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Optional Debug (Debug RPMs)                                                               344
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-debug-rh-common/7Server/x86_64                                                        Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 RH Common Debug (Debug RPMs)                                                                7
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-debug-rhscl/7Server/x86_64                                                            Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 RHSCL Debug (Debug RPMs)                                                                   98
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-debug-supplementary/7Server/x86_64                                                    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Supplementary Debug (Debug RPMs)                                                            0
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras/7Server/x86_64                                                                 Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Extra(RPMs)                                                                                12
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional/7Server/x86_64                                                               Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Optional (RPMs)                                                                         4,377
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases/7Server/x86_64                                                               Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 (RPMs)                                                                                  4,753
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases-debug/7Server/x86_64                                                         Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Debug (Debug RPMs)                                                                      2,040
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases-source/7Server/x86_64                                                        Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 (SRPMs)                                                                                     0
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-rh-common/7Server/x86_64                                                              Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 RH Common (RPMs)                                                                           53
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-rhscl/7Server/x86_64                                                                  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 RHSCL (RPMs)                                                                              779
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-source-extras/7Server/x86_64                                                          Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Extra (SRPMs)                                                                              12
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-source-optional/7Server/x86_64                                                        Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Optional (SRPMs)                                                                        1,474
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-source-rh-common/7Server/x86_64                                                       Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 RH Common (SRPMs)                                                                          43
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-source-rhscl/7Server/x86_64                                                           Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 RHSCL (SRPMs)                                                                             424
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-source-supplementary/7Server/x86_64                                                   Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Supplementary (SRPMs)                                                                       0
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-supplementary/7Server/x86_64                                                          Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Supplementary (RPMs)                                                                       36
repolist: 24,759
[root@ip-10-146-180-60 ~]#
```

I've tried Google it, but was unable to find it either... any ideas where else I should look for it?

Comment: If you don't mind doing something that the package manager won't like, download the rpm from the site in the mirror, and manually install LWP::UserAgent from cpan. Honestly, you might want to just download the source code for awstats and install it manually. Anyway, to install the perl module manually, run the "cpan" command and then (when you get to the cpan cli) run "install MSCHILLI/libwww-perl-6.08.tar.gz" - which should install LWP::UserAgent. You can either then install awstats from awstats.org, or the rpm using the "rpm --isntall --nodeps" command.

Comment: `cpan` is out of the option, `perl-libwww-perl` is available via rpm (http://pastebin.com/W6rKd1cZ), but i don't see `perl-LWP-UserAgent` in that list either.

Comment: perl-libwww-perl does contain .../LWP/UserAgent.pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after `yum install perl-libwww-perl` (and bunch of dependencies):

```
Sep 17 21:40:19 Installed: 1:perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.061-4.el7.x86_64
Sep 17 21:40:19 Installed: perl-LWP-MediaTypes-6.02-2.el7.noarch
Sep 17 21:40:19 Installed: perl-Data-Dumper-2.145-3.el7.x86_64
Sep 17 21:40:19 Installed: perl-Encode-Locale-1.03-5.el7.noarch
Sep 17 21:40:19 Installed: perl-HTML-Tagset-3.20-15.el7.noarch
Sep 17 21:40:19 Installed: perl-Net-LibIDN-0.12-15.el7.x86_64
Sep 17 21:40:19 Installed: 1:perl-TimeDate-2.30-2.el7.noarch
Sep 17 21:40:19 Installed: perl-HTTP-Date-6.02-8.el7.noarch
Sep 17 21:40:19 Installed: perl-File-Listing-6.04-7.el7.noarch
Sep 17 21:40:19 Installed: perl-Net-SSLeay-1.55-3.el7.x86_64
Sep 17 21:40:20 Installed: perl-Business-ISBN-Data-20120719.001-2.el7.noarch
Sep 17 21:40:20 Installed: perl-Business-ISBN-2.06-2.el7.noarch
Sep 17 21:40:20 Installed: perl-URI-1.60-9.el7.noarch
Sep 17 21:40:20 Installed: perl-WWW-RobotRules-6.02-5.el7.noarch
Sep 17 21:40:20 Installed: perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2-2.061-3.el7.x86_64
Sep 17 21:40:20 Installed: perl-IO-Compress-2.061-2.el7.noarch
Sep 17 21:40:20 Installed: perl-IO-HTML-1.00-2.el7.noarch
Sep 17 21:40:20 Installed: perl-HTTP-Message-6.06-6.el7.noarch
Sep 17 21:40:20 Installed: perl-HTTP-Cookies-6.01-5.el7.noarch
Sep 17 21:40:20 Installed: perl-HTML-Parser-3.71-4.el7.x86_64
Sep 17 21:40:20 Installed: perl-HTTP-Daemon-6.01-5.el7.noarch
Sep 17 21:40:20 Installed: perl-HTTP-Negotiate-6.01-5.el7.noarch
Sep 17 21:40:20 Installed: perl-IO-Socket-IP-0.21-4.el7.noarch
Sep 17 21:40:20 Installed: perl-IO-Socket-SSL-1.94-3.el7.noarch
Sep 17 21:40:21 Installed: perl-Net-HTTP-6.06-2.el7.noarch
Sep 17 21:40:21 Installed: perl-libwww-perl-6.05-2.el7.noarch
```

I was able to install `awstats`:

```
[root@ip-10-146-180-60 ~]# rpm -q awstats
awstats-7.3-1.noarch
[root@ip-10-146-180-60 ~]#
```